# Passing Javascript from Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, function

I was trying to call a Javascript function using Flash. The function is called when the user clicks on the Enter Site button. The Firebug console registers the button as being clicked returning 'closeIntro is not defined'. The function is defined at the top so I'm not quite sure what is going on.

Site having issue.
http://sandbox.solutionsbydesign.com/greenway_wp/

Site I pulled snippet from
blog.codefidelity.com/?p=15

Comment: Using that method ? or the link I posted worked fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you using [ExternalInterface](http://help.adobe.com/pl_PL/AS3LCR/Flash_10.0/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html) class and not doing intros for websites in general [(first link found on google)](http://angryaussie.wordpress.com/2009/07/15/should-your-website-have-a-flash-intro/)[(second link)](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/webdesign/flash_web_site_intros_usage_advantages_disadvantages.php3)[(third link)](http://www.wakeuplater.com/website-building/places-that-flash-does-not-belong.aspx).

Comment: I completely agree with not doing intros ( we are not in '98 anymore ) but unfortunately I don't make those decisions - I'm just a tool.